# Why in a Facebook Ad REACH campaign LANDING_PAGE_VIEWS gives me an error?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I created a Facebook Ad REACH campaign (Traffic if I create campaign from Facebook Ad Manager).
As obtimization_goal I set LANDING_PAGE_VIEWS or LINK_CLICKS (display of the landing page with Ad Manager).
WEBSITE as destination type.
The above message error appears:
You can't use the selected optimization goal for your campaign objective. Please select a different goal, or edit your campaign.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Without better reproduction step, it sounds like this is a validation error based on the objectives and optimzation goals.

Please refer to the validation documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/validation/

I would link to the exact piece, but from your question I cannot fully understand your setup.

Thanks